# How to hide console window using python esky 0.9.8?

Tags: python, py2exe, esky

I currently have an exe that I created using python bundled up with the esky package(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/esky).
My setup file looks like this

```
setup(name='pythonApp',
  version = "0.1",
  scripts=[pythonAppEXE],
  options = {'bdist_esky':{
      'freezer_module': 'py2exe',
      },},
```

)
Now i know that in py2exe you can use windows=[pythonAppEXE] instead of scripts=[pythonAppEXE], but unfortunately I cannot replace scripts=[pythonAppEXE] when using esky.
So how can I create an exe that doesn't have a console?

Answer (score 1):

```
from esky.bdist_esky import Executable  

executables = [Executable('hi.py', icon='stack.ico', gui_only=True)]

setup(name="hellow world",
    version = '0.1',
    scripts = executables)
```